Is it OK to remove continuous vinyl siding when I enclose a porch and install vinyl plank flooring?
I want to install vinyl plank flooring and and make our recently enclosed porch (formerly a screened in porch) feel more like another room of the house.
The way I see it, I have two options:

Leave the vinyl siding in place. The problem is figuring out how to make the LVT flooring fit nicely against vinyl siding.

Remove the vinyl siding and install shiplap, drywall, or something similar. The problem is that one of the walls has continuous vinyl siding which runs up from the basement wall, right through the porch and up to the 2nd floor.


Is it safe to cut out the continuous vinyl siding from inside the porch? Am I asking for trouble?
Taking the vinyl siding off the other walls will be straightforward as it's capped with J channels there.
Problem Wall (floor, 2 pictures of ceiling at different angles, view from outside to see how vinyl runs through porch and up):

Problem Wall floor level as requested:

Other 2 walls where vinyl siding actually is capped within the porch (just for informational but my plan is just to remove that like any other vinyl siding):


Please post more pics of the floor at the wall. Pics of the walls and ceiling do nothing to help find a solution to your problem.

Sure thing @RMDman!
Updated post with a pic of the problem wall at the floor.  Couple different shots of it.
I'd like to just pull all that siding off but not sure if I'm going to cause a problem at the ceiling or the floor since there is no J channel.  No water should be getting in here but if I cut the vinyl siding then I know there is no going back :)

I mean, if it's properly enclosed, I'd want to get rid of the siding and all such accoutrements.  There shouldn't actually be any reason you couldn't drywall instead.

@isherwood I've edited to remove the fluff and focus on what I felt OP was clearly concerned with, which is whether it is OK to cut into or remove the vinyl siding on the wall where it is continuous from ground to roof, beyond the confines of the porch. The flooring part is ancillary at best (only a concern if the answer to the main question is "no") and should not be considered an entirely separate question.


Problem is figuring out how to make the LVT flooring fit nicely against vinyl siding

Flooring installers (or DIYers) can cut LVT however they need to with just a utility knife/razor blade. Having it fit up against the vinyl siding snugly shouldn't be that much of an issue, as any flooring installers should use the common construction technique known as scribing (or coping--scribing technically refers to drawing the cut line, and coping refers to making an irregular cut to fit one piece of material perfectly to another) to make sure that any angles or irregular cuts that need to be made fit perfectly with the angles of the wall.
LVT, just like wood floor, is installed with a slight expansion gap (shouldn't need to be more than 1/4") between the wall and the LVT to allow for expansion and contraction, so whoever installs it shouldn't need to get it right up against the wall.

Essentially the vinyl siding runs up from the basement wall, right through the porch and up to the 2nd floor.  [...] Is it safe to cut the vinyl siding? Am I asking for trouble? How would you finish it?

It's hard to tell from the photos exactly how the roof of the porch is fastened and sealed to the vinyl siding... but given you've already put furniture and windows and wood floors in there, I'm guessing it's probably pretty well-sealed from the elements?
If that's the case, you can rip all that vinyl out and put in your preferred wall material. I did the same recently for a sunroom of my own, replacing vinyl siding from a former exterior wall with drywall (although mine went from a screened-in room to a 4-season fully conditioned space).  Or, you can just cut enough to put in baseboard and ceiling trim if you really like the look of vinyl siding in your porch.
To be safe, since the vinyl is continuous through the porch floor and ceiling to the outside, my recommendation is to use 1x4 PVC boards as floor and ceiling trim. PVC boards cut and paint like wood, but are excellent for wet locations (they're made from the same base material as your vinyl siding); it does not swell or warp if exposed to moisture like wood will... given that the vinyl siding in your case is continuous from ground to roof, the porch may not be perfectly sealed forever (unless you're the exceedingly rare kind of homeowner who stays on top of maintenance like re-caulking exterior joints every 5-7 years.), and you'll appreciate having that PVC trim in place, so long as it, too, is sealed with caulk on the inside.
The 1x4 trim will also do a good job of hiding that expansion joint from the LVT flooring, and it is all white, so you will have your nice white color bordering the LVT like you asked for without needing to paint (unless you want a glossier finish).
If you decide to rip out all of the siding and replace it with drywall, be extra sure to caulk below the porch as needed to seal it against moisture and air traveling upward from below, and in the room as needed.
